# Cannot install rvm to HOME path on arch linux

Tags: linux, bash, path, console, rvm

My problem is that I can't install RVM to $HOME path. My OS is Arch Linux.
Single-user tutorial says (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/RVM)
`Note: This will install to your home directory only (~/.rvm), and will not touch the standard Arch ruby package, which is in /usr.`
But in my case, when I was running

```
[*** ~]$ curl -L get.rvm.io > rvm-install
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   194  100   194    0     0    541      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   541
100 24535  100 24535    0     0  52737      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 52737
[*** ~]$ bash < ./rvm-install
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/rvm’: Permission denied
```

But I don't want to install to /rvm directory, I'd like to install to my $HOME path directory.
Help me guys please. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: The `rvm-install` script is the one that does the work here.  If you look at the code, you will see that it wants to install in `$HOME/rvm` (line 546).  Since it looks like it wants to install in `/rvm` for you, I guess your `$HOME` variable is not set ?!?  I just quiclkly read the script, its support is out of scope for SO, you should see RVM sites and support forum for this (if they have one).

Comment: Looks like option `--path` could be of help here...